# Mock member-call when parameters do not match exactly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have a method that I´m trying to mock using NSubstitute:

```
Foo MyMethod(IEnumerable<string> args);
```

I want the method to return `new Foo { ID = 1 }` for a call where the `args`-collection has exactly one item called `"Item1"`. However when the collection contains only `"Item2"` I´d like to return another instance of `Foo`.

So I wrote this code:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<MyType>();
mock.MyMethod(new[] { "Item1" }).Returns(new Foo { ID = 1 });
mock.MyMethod(new[] { "Item2" }).Returns(new Foo { ID = 2 });
```

In my calling code I have something like this:

```
var foo = myType.MyMethod(new[] { "Item1" });
```

However the mock isn´t executed as arrays are compared using reference-equality. So as I have *two instances* of `string[]` *sharing the same values* they are considered unequal and thus we don´t jump to the mocked return-statement.

So what I´d like to achieve is no matter what exact type of collection we provide to the method the mock should just distinguish on the collections items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Arg.Is` syntax to do the check yourself:

```
mock.MyMethod(Arg.Is<string[]>(a => a.Contains("Item1"))).Returns(new Foo { ID = 1 });
mock.MyMethod(Arg.Is<string[]>(a => a.Contains("Item2"))).Returns(new Foo { ID = 2 });
```

See here for more information: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-args/

Comment: I changed the `Contains`-check to `a.Single() == "Item1"` to ensure there´s exactly *one item* and its value is `"Item1"`. However this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can do anything in there, as long as it's a valid expression. I don't know about NSubstitute but at least with Moq you can't do certain things like optional variables and the likes